# Onblur event in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We have the below fields in the UI which has onblur event implemented. When we execute the steps manually, it works, but when we use Webdriver 2.45 version to execute the same steps it fails to get updated value in the total field.

HTML code:

```
<input name="percent_list" id="percent_list" type="text" value="1" align="right" class="formInput" onblur="calculate();">

<input name="percent_sell" id="percent_sell" type="text" value="1" align="right" class="formInput" onblur="calculate();">

<input name="total_commision" id="total_commision" type="text" value="2.00" readonly="yes" class="formInput">
```

Test data:
- Field 1 : 1.00
- Field 2: 1.00
- Verification Field ( total ): 2.00

Steps:
- Enter value for Field 1 & 2.
- Verify whether Total field has the total sum of field 1 and 2.

Observation: We see that as the event is onblur , it works manually but with IE browser and Selenium , the UI is not getting auto populated with the sum value.

Tried methods:
- Sendkeys : didn't worked. Tried clicking on other webelement also didn't worked.
- Used Java script editor also didn't worked. we are able to update the field 1 and 2, but the field total sum doesn't auto sum.
- tried using Keys.TAB also. it didn't worked.

code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("percent_list")).sendKeys("2.5");
           //JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
          // jse.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])", driver.findElement(By.id("percent_sell")), Keys.TAB);
           //jse.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])", driver.findElement(By.id("referral_fee_percent")), Keys.TAB);
           driver.findElement(By.id("listing_agent_bonus")).click();
```

Any suggestion to resolve this onblur related behavior?

Comment: Did you try driver.findElement(By.id("percent_sell")).sendKeys("2.5", Keys.TAB),

Comment: Yes, it didn't worked.

Comment: try driver.executeScript('return calculate();') after input text to the second box. if this way work, but not as user experience. you need consider it's acceptable.

Comment: google for "javascript trigger onblur event" and use it with JavascriptExecutor.execute

Answer (score 0):

There a are two ways to do it using Selenium `JavascriptExecutor`, once you have entered value in the field you can make use of either following:

```
 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 jse.executeScript('calculate();');
```

or if you are expecting an output which you want to receive in Selenium :

```
Object value = jse.executeScript('return calculate();');
```

**UPDATE:**

You can also try following code:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

WebElement input1 = driver.findElement(By.id("percent_list"));
WebElement input2 = driver.findElement(By.id("percent_sell"));

input1.sendKeys(your_value);
jse.executeScript('arguments[0].onblur()', input1);

input2.sendKeys(your_value);
jse.executeScript('arguments[0].onblur()', input2);
```

Comment: Thanks Kushal, Let me try out this.

Comment: it's strange, i guess it should be work.  Can you try open developer tool of IE by press F12, then exuecute  calculate() in console Tab, what will happen? or you use latest version to try

Answer (score 0):

**Analysis**

The blur method has no effect on an element that is not the active element in the document.

As the InternetExplorerDriver is Windows-only, it attempts to use so-called "native", or OS-level events to perform mouse and keyboard operations in the browser. This is in contrast to using simulated JavaScript events for the same operations.

I guess the click() and press Tab key by **your InternetExplorerDriver** not change the active element, so the blur won't be trigger even you click on other element.

**Solution**

I prepare a javascript code snippet using selenium-webdriver Nodejs package, it open [github login page](https://github.com/login) and input username and Tab key by sendKeys()

I run the script on my Chrome/Firefox/IE 11, after sendKeys() call, I noticed the password text box obtain the focus from page and script print out the active element is also the password textbox on the 3 browsers.

Could you run below code on your IE browser and watch the password text box can obtain the focus? the print out active element is also the password text box?

**if above two answer are yes**, modify the code to test your page by changing url to your site and change username text box to your 'Field 1', then run to see what will happend.

**if any one of two answer is no**, change your InternetExplorerDriver version, and run again

Thanks for your time to run my script to prove my guess, hope we can learn more from this issue, not only use a solution by google search, but don't know why.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    Key = webdriver.Key,
    Capabilities = webdriver.Capabilities;

function getDriver(browserName) {
    if (browserName === 'internet explorer') {
        let capabilities = Capabilities.ie();
        capabilities.set('ignoreProtectedModeSettings', true);
        capabilities.set('ignoreZoomSetting', true);

        return new webdriver.Builder()
            .forBrowser(browserName)
            .withCapabilities(capabilities)
            .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
            .build();
    } else {
        return new webdriver.Builder()
            .forBrowser(browserName)
            .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
            .build();
    }
}

function login_github(driver) {
    driver.get('https://github.com/login');

    driver.sleep(5000);

    driver.findElement(By.css('#login_field')).sendKeys('abc@gmail.com', Key.TAB);

    driver.sleep(2000);

    // expect password text box obtain focus and become active element
    // below code should print out the html code of password text box
    // <input class="form-control form-control input-block" id="password" 
    // name="password" tabindex="2" type="password">
    driver.executeScript("return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.activeElement);")
        .then(function(html) {
            console.log('activeElement html: ' + html);
        })

    driver.sleep(5000);

    driver.quit();
}

//run on chrome
// login_github(getDriver('chrome'));
//run on firefox
// login_github(getDriver('firefox'));
//run on ie
login_github(getDriver('internet explorer'));
```

FYI, I used RemoteWebDriver in my code, so I used Nodejs package: [webdriver-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriver-manager) to setup selenium server on my local. I used below version:

```
standalone-server 3.4.0
InternetExplorerDriver-32bit 3.5.1
chromedriver 2.30
geckodriver v0.19.0
chrome browser 60
firefox browser 55
ie browser 11
```

Below is my command to install webdriver.exe and standalone-sever

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.standalone=3.4.0 --versions.chrome=2.30 --verions.ie=3.5.1 --version.gecko=v0.19.0
```

Below is my command to start selenium server:

```
webdriver-manager start --versions.standalone=3.4.0 --versions.chrome=2.30 --verions.ie=3.5.1 --version.gecko=v0.19.0
```

Comment: Thanks Young, Let me try out this solution..!

Comment: I'm using Selenium 2.45 , Hence i was not able to test this.

Comment: what block you to test the script?  any error reported?  could you tell me versions of your selenium-standalone,  browser version, webdriver version, can  you give a try on other browser, like chrome?